# PyTorch Modulenotfound

Tags: python

I've succesfully installed torch with pip in

> c:\users\utente\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages

when I try to import on VSCode that's the error. Any solution?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\UTENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    ctypes.CDLL(dll)
  File "C:\Users\UTENTE\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato
```

that's my python version:

> Python 3.7.7 (tags/v3.7.7:d7c567b08f, Mar 10 2020, 10:41:24) [MSC
> v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

any other module in the same directory works fine.

Comment: What was the exact command that you've used? Also check if you are in the required virtual environment while importing

Comment: i'm just open a new file.py and import torch

Comment: Can you import other modules? What does PYTHONPATH output?

Comment: yes I can import other modules without problem. PYTHONPATH: Python 3.7.7 64-bit